# Network configuration to allow Android to generate Push-Tokens

Tags: android, push-notification, token

I am making an android app that will be used inside a closed network where there is a security and network configuration that need to be taken for each IP or HTTP that needs to be used

But I noticed that my testing Android device is giving the error

```
E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:xxxxxxxxxx>, App: com.google.android.talk, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.peopleapi.readwrite https://www.googleapis.com/auth/hangouts https://www.googleapis.com/auth/identity.plus.page.impersonation  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.native
pqx: Error when calling server.
```

And:

```
W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: NetworkError
```

So my application is not being able to generate the token to be used to received push notificaitons

What are the ports/IPs that need to be opened and allowed through the network firewall to allow the devices to receive the notifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking blocked HTTP requests sent from the Android device to the network

It showed that the network security firewall is blocking the domain `android.clients.google.com`

Once this domain is allowed again and disconnected the Android device from the network then reconnected it generated the push-token and received the pending push notifications that were sent before